# What to do with a danger of literal types?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I translate a big JS project to TS project and noticed something. For example I have a module, which looks like this:

WinConstants.ts

```
export = {
  "no_win":0,
  "win":1,
  "big_win":2,
  "mega_win":3
}
```

I want to make it really constant, so I restrict it like this:

WinConstants.ts

```
class WinConstants{
  readonly no_win:0;
  readonly win:1;
  readonly big_win:2;
  readonly mega_win:3;
}

export = new WinConstants();
```

Pretty cool huh? Done with it, now go translate next module. Right? Not so fast. I forgot to replace `":"`s with `"="`s and TypeScript **does not warn me about it**. All values are now `undefined`. It may go under the radar until I see it in runtime... Welcome back to JS uncertainty! The whole point of translating things to TS, when you rely on compiler's errors, just cancelled itself...  If there had been no literal types, this would have never happened, because literal numbers in this case wouldn't have been types.

So what to do? Don't get me wrong, I love literal types, they help a lot, but the syntax is now against me. These kind of things may go unnoticed not only when I translate, but when I write something and accidentally put `:` in JSON style rather than `=` sign.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Neither your first, nor your second approach are good, as you are exporting a constant object or an instance of a class.

You should use an `enum` for this ([more info](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)).

```
export enum WinConstants {
  NO_WIN = 0,
  WIN = 1,
  BIG_WIN = 2,
  MEGA_WIN = 3
}
```

Comment: You're right, enum is the best structure for this. I used this example only to demonstrate it. But what if, as I said, I accidentally use JS object notation instead of = somewhere else in code and get no compiler mistakes? Maybe I should use smth like `--strictNullChecks`, which won't let me leave those fields undefined...